# bluetooth.connect() yields BluetToothError(112), while connect via bluetoothctl works well

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to learn to communicate with a Bluetooth device using Python but my first steps fail.

I can successfully connect to a given device using `bluetoothctl`:

```
[bluetooth]# connect F5:EE:1C:40:21:44
Attempting to connect to F5:EE:1C:40:21:44
[CHG] Device F5:EE:1C:40:21:44 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0xa9bd)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F5_EE_1C_40_21_44/service000a
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0xa9bd)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F5_EE_1C_40_21_44/service000b
    53300001-0023-4bd4-bbd5-a6920e4c5653
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x6f54)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F5_EE_1C_40_21_44/service000b/char000c
    53300002-0023-4bd4-bbd5-a6920e4c5653
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x6604)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F5_EE_1C_40_21_44/service000b/char000e
    53300003-0023-4bd4-bbd5-a6920e4c5653
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0164)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F5_EE_1C_40_21_44/service000b/char000e/desc0010
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
```

but trying to connect via Python3's pybluez module results in an exception being raised:

```
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect(("F5:EE:1C:40:21:44", 1))
...
BluetoothError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2af54455681d> in <module>
----> 1 sock.connect(("F5:EE:1C:40:21:44", 1))

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py in connect(self, *args, **kwargs)

BluetoothError: [Errno 112] Host is down
```

What am I doing wrong here? Very likely I'm just missing the very basics of Bluetooth development - maybe you can give me a direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the log information you shared from when you connected with `bluetoothctl`, it looks like you are connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.

The commands you are you issuing with PyBlueZ is to connect to a Bluetooth Classic (BR/EDR) device and I suspect that is why the device is not responding.

PyBlueZ uses a deprecated API for BlueZ. The currently supported APIs are documented at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

It is the [Device API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt) that is used for connecting to a device. Below is an example of how to use it with the generic D-Bus library [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/)

```py
from time import sleep
import pydbus

DEVICE_ADDR = 'F5:EE:1C:40:21:44' #  device address


# DBus object paths
BLUEZ_SERVICE = 'org.bluez'
device_path = f"/org/bluez/hci0/dev_{DEVICE_ADDR.replace(':', '_')}"

# setup dbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
device = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, device_path)

# Connect to device
device.Connect()
sleep(10)
device.Disconnect()
```

Comment: That's it, thanks - I got an exception on the first try `KeyError: 'object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'` but all I had to do was to run a device scan first.

Comment: Yes it needs to be in the BlueZ cache before you can connect. Once you have connected to the device once or paired the device it should no get flushed from the cache. There is a DBus API for doing the [scan/discovery](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt?h=5.63#n12). There is also an experimental method called [ConnectDevice](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt?h=5.63#n170) to connect to a device without running discovery first. Experimental APIs need a change in the daemon and are best avoided.